# Flask Import Error

Tags: python, flask

I'm running the following code in a file called **init**.py that works.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, Response


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index4.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

When I try to import a file (from "file" import "function") or a python (import "package") it causes a 500 error. The code that causes the error is below.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, Response
from file import function

app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
    def homepage():
        return render_template('index4.html')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: does the package exist? What is the error exactly?

Comment: There is an error finding the package. The package name is mibian.

The package is not part of the standard python library and has to be installed. 

pip install mibian installs the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to the permissions on the directory that contained the site packages.

By changing the permissions on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and adding WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to the FlaskApp.conf file I was able to resolve the problem.

Thanks @mmenschig for the help.